# Individual list addition in python

Tags: python, list

If I have these lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

how do I add each individual element in the list a by all in list b?

```
final_list = [5,6,7,6,7,8,7,8,9]
```

I have tried using 2 for loops but as an amateur, I imagine there is a more effective way. Cheers!

Comment: Please, show your effort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
# Multiplication
final_list = [x*y for x in a for y in b]
```

> [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18]

```
# Addition
final_list = [x+y for x in a for y in b]
```

> [5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 4):

You could do addition also similarly as the previous answers,

```
>>> [i+j for i in a for j in b]
[5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to calculate the cartesian product of `a` and `b`, and then calculate the product/sum of each pair:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1,2,3];b = [4,5,6]
>>> list(itertools.product(a,b)) # This step isn't needed. It's just to show the result of itertools.product
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> [i + j for i, j in itertools.product(a, b)]
[5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [i * j for i, j in itertools.product(a, b)]
[4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about handling n lists?

```
from itertools import product

def listSum(lists):
  return [sum(list) for list in product(*lists)]

print(listSum(([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))) #=> [5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9]
print(listSum(([1,2,3], ))) #=> [1, 2, 3]
print(listSum(([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]))) #=> [12, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15, 14, 15, 16, 13, 14, 15, 14, 15, 16, 15, 16, 17, 14, 15, 16, 15, 16, 17, 16, 17, 18]
```

Comment: Why not use `sum` instead of `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list, 0)` ?

Comment: In the original question he asked for the product not the sum.... so while editing i used the same logic, but yes it can be simplified